# How to define a relative rule in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

How to define a relative rule in Prolog?

This is what I got so far:

```
spouce(X,Y) :-
    wife(X,Y).

spouce(X,Y) :-
    husband(X,Y).

relative-by-blood(X,Y) :-
    ancestor(Z,X),
    ancestor(Z,Y).


relative(X,Y) :-
    relative-by-blood(X,Y).

relative(X,Y) :-
    spouce(X,Y).

relative(X,Y) :-
    relative-by-blood(X,Z), %<- not sure what to do here.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you describe it in more details?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information.  See my answer below based on what you have given us so far, but I have a feeling there's more to the story than we're getting in the question.

Comment: Under ISO Prolog syntax, unquoted atoms cannot contain the hyphen-minus, so `relative-by-blood(X,Y)` probably won't be parsed as you want it to be. Instead, you'll get `-(-(relative,by),blood(X,Y))`. I think you want `relative_by_blood(X,Y)`, which parses as a two-argument compound term with functor `relative_by_blood` and arguments `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, I think you need to rewrite `relative(X,Y)` as:

```
relative(X,Y) :- relative-by-blood(X,Y) ; spouce(X,Y).
```

From there we need more info (I'll edit to add to my answer if we get more).  Also, can you give us your `ancestor` rules?